# Find the exact value of sin(2u)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the exact values of $\sin(2u)$ using double angle formulas

$\sin(u)=\frac{-8}{17}, \pi<u<\frac{3\pi}{2}$
but when I draw out the triangle, the missing side length is greater then 17 it's $\sqrt{353}$ which is about 18.8.

I don't where to go from here without getting $\cos(u)$

Comment: Well, get $\cos u$!

Comment: right but the the new side length is bigger then the hypotenuse, is it because its in the 3rd quad that its -18.8?

Comment: Can't you just use $cos(u)= \pm\sqrt{1 - sin^2(u)}$ , and decide if the root is positive or negative based on the given interval of u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For trigonometry problems, you should preferably consider the trigonometric circle, not triangles.

$$\cos^2u=1-\Bigl(\frac{-8}{17}\Bigr)^2=\frac{225}{289}=\Bigl(\frac{15}{17}\Bigr)^2.$$
Now, on the interval $\Bigl[\pi,\frac{3\pi}2\Bigr]$, $\cos u \le 0$, so $\cos u=-\frac{15}{17}$, and
$$\sin 2u=2\cdot\frac{-8}{17}\cdot\frac{-15}{17}=\frac{240}{289}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

In a right-angled triangle with leg $8$ and hypotenuse $17$, what  is the other leg?

Can you now compute cosine?

**HINT 2**

The other leg is $\sqrt{17^2-8^2} < 17$...

Comment: it's $\sqrt{353}$ but that is bigger then the hypo.

Comment: @EricBrown see the update

Comment: Your right I used -8 when i should've squared it first then solved for x